# -s flag on rails generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran across a tutorial that had the following syntax:

```
rails generate model User name:string -s
```

What is the `-s` for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing in `rails generate model --help` would give you the answer you need:

```
Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
```

On the last part you see:

```
Skip files that already exist
```